# How to translate this phrase about forgetting oneself in Plato's Apology?

Tags: greek, translation-check, plato

I'm translating the first sentence from [Plato's Apology](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.01.0169%3Atext%3DApol.), and encountered a difficulty.

> ὅτι μὲν ὑμεῖς, ὦ ἄνδρες Ἀθηναῖοι, πεπόνθατε ὑπὸ τῶν ἐμῶν κατηγόρων,
>   οὐκ οἶδα: ἐγὼ δ᾽ οὖν καὶ αὐτὸς ὑπ᾽ αὐτῶν ὀλίγου ἐμαυτοῦ ἐπελαθόμην,
>   οὕτω πιθανῶς ἔλεγον.
>
> How you, o men of Athens, have been affected by my accusers, I do not
>   know: but I ... so persuasively did they speak.

As you can see, I'm having trouble translating ἐγὼ δ᾽ οὖν καὶ αὐτὸς ὑπ᾽ αὐτῶν ὀλίγου ἐμαυτοῦ ἐπελαθόμην. I think the verb ἐπελαθόμην is 1st sg aorist and means "I forgot". But how would you make sense of οὖν καὶ αὐτὸς ὑπ᾽ αὐτῶν ὀλίγου ἐμαυτοῦ?

I think the preposition ὑπ᾽ is part of what's throwing me off.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a bit of a convoluted sentence! The key is that the three genitives here have nothing to do with each other—one is a genitive of agent, one is <s>a genitive of quantity</s> *a specific idiom*, and one is the object of a verb that governs the genitive.

> …δ᾽ οὖν καὶ…
> *And seriously…*
>
> …ἐγὼ…αὐτὸς…
> *…I myself…*
>
> …ὀλίγου…
> *…almost…*
>
> …ἐμαυτοῦ ἐπελαθόμην
> *…forgot myself…*
>
> …ὑπ᾽ αὐτῶν…
> *because of them.*

As a whole, "and indeed, even I almost started to forget who I was because of them". He's saying the accusers are misrepresenting him so persuasively he's forgetting his own real identity.

*Ὑπ᾽ αὐτῶν* is expressing the cause of the forgetting, referring back to the *κατήγοροι* from the previous clause—this use is most common with passive verbs, but sometimes shows up with non-passives too.

Comment: ὀλίγου = "almost" rather than "a little bit".

Comment: @TKR Ahh, right, looked it up and apparently that's a specific idiom. Corrected!

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation!